# i have more than five image in my canvas how to make one image to blink is there any way i could do it

Tags: html, canvas

i have more than five image in my canvas how to make one image to blink is there any way i could do it.here is my problem i having  more than five image in a canvas i want to blink a single image only.is there any way i could do it.i searched all over internet and i could not find a valid answer..................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: what do you mean five images in canvas? How are they located relatively to each other, do they intersect?

Comment: no they don't intersect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two solutions that I can think of :

1. Create different canvases for each image. So that one canvas has one image in it and then apply some changes to the whole canvas.
2. If you have the x and y coordinates of the image you want to change and you know it's width and height then you can do the following :

   `var imgd = context.getImageData(x, y, width, height);`

   `var pix = imgd.data;`

pix now contains array that has information about pixels of your image. Therefore, by changing it you can modify your image also.